# How do I set the state of a service to disabled in an offline mounted system

Tags: systemd, services

I have the filesystem of a server which is offline mounted locally in a root shell, how do I set the state of postfix to disabled, so the next time, I start the server postfix will not automatically start?

Comment: It took me a while to figure what was *offline mounted* to mean. Not offline with respect to a network/connectivity, but rather that the mounted filesystem (containing a systemd init is not active i.e. running and PID=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mounted the root of the filesystem in `/mnt/serverdisk`,

```
cd /mnt/serverdisk
rm -v etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/postfix.service
```

This should be enough.

Here's a demo on CentOS 8 showing removing the symlink does not break anything:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 8.0.1905 (Core)
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl get-default
multi-user.target
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# runlevel
N 3
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl is-enabled postfix
enabled
[root@localhost ~]# rm -v /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/postfix.service
rm: remove symbolic link '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/postfix.service'? y
removed '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/postfix.service'
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl is-enabled postfix
disabled
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl enable postfix
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/postfix.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service.
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl is-enabled postfix
enabled
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: great! dows this destroy anything? or can I safely enable it later in the running server without problems?

Comment: Does not destroy anything. You can enable it later again with the `service enable postfix` command or `systemctl enable postfix` command.

Answer (score 1):

chroot into the mounted new system:

```
  mkdir /media/tmp/
  mount /dev/vg0/vm01.tmp-disk-snapshot /media/tmp/
  mount -t proc none /media/tmp/proc
  mount --bind /dev /media/tmp/dev
  mount -t sysfs sysfs /media/tmp/sys
  chroot /media/tmp/ /bin/bash
```

Do your work and exit

```
systemctl disable postfix
exit
```